# Ajax sends two empty arrays and one filled, PHP receives only the full one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm completely new to PHP. Working with ajax, php and WordPress I'm sending an object with ajax:

```
let import_data = {
 action: 'import_data',
 data: {
  first_array: [], // this one is empty
  second_array: [], // this one too
  third_array: [1,2,3] // this one is full
 }
};
```

I've checked the import_data object many times right before it was sent. The php, however, always receives:

```
import_data = {
 action: 'import_data',
 data: {
  third_array: [1,2,3]
 }
}
```

The question is why is that happening and how can I achieve receiving all arrays, whether they are empty or not, i.e.

```
import_data = {
 action: 'import_data',
 data: {
  first_array: [],
  second_array: [], 
  third_array: [1,2,3]
 }
}
```

I need to refactor a lot of code now due to this issue so I'm trying to solve it as easy as possible, but if there is a common known right way to deal with it I'll use it. Thanks in advance!

P.S. In case you wondering, yes, if all arrays being sent are full, php will receive all of them.

**UPD** In the comments I got I might've wanted to add contentType or json.strngify my data. It didn't help, but I might do it wrong, so I'll try to partly show my code below:

```
var import_data = {
     action: 'start_import',
     sliced_batch: {
        rows_to_add: [],
        rows_to_delete: [],
        rows_to_update: [1,2,3,4,5,...]
     }
};
    

function ajax_call(import_data) {
// ... processes

 jQuery.ajax({
            url: start_import_ajax.url, // url from php file
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "text; charset=utf-8", // sending string with cyrillic (ukrainian lng)
            dataType: 'application/json', // want  to recieve json
            data: JSON.stringify(import_data), 
            success: function(response) { 
               // ... processes import_data ...
               if(it is the end of data) return;
               else ajax_call(import_data);
            },
            error: function(e) {
              // here is where I end up
            }

}
```

PHP side is now pretty shy, as I just made a pause and wanted to see my data in console:

```
function start_import_callback() {
   
    echo json_decode($_POST);
    echo $_POST;
    echo json_decode($_POST['sliced_batch']);
    echo $_POST['sliced_batch'];

 
    wp_die();
}
```

I've tried all `echo`'s one by one, but always saw:

```
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "0",
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "error"
}
```

When NOT stringifying and NOT specifying contentType/dataType it returns:

```
{
             action: 'import_data',
     sliced_batch: {
    rows_to_update:
            {
                "ID": "00000006125",
                "CatalogueNumber": "bla, bla",
                "Category": "bla, bla",
                "Manufacturer": "bla",
                "Nomenclature": "blablablablabla",
                "NomenclatureUkrainian": "bla",
                "StockStatus": "instock",
                "Price": "2 315",
                "Parent": "blabla",
                "Sorting": "99"
            },
            {},...
        ]
    }
}
```

So, rows_to_delete: [] and rows_to_add: [] are missing...

Comment: wich jquery version do you use ?

Comment: @AsmaMech version 3.3.2

Comment: What is your content type when you send it?

Comment: @nice_dev it is not specified, but I'll try looking at it closer with different values now

Comment: @ЮрийДзбановский Do you also `JSON.stringify(import_data)` before sending?

Comment: @nice_dev yes, I tried it, but got
`
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "0",
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "error"
}
`

Comment: @ЮрийДзбановский What was the content-type header when you sent data from ajax to PHP? Can you also show how you process it on your PHP side? Please edit and add these details in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jQuery `dataType` options wrong!
The `dataType:` value should be `'json'` not `'application/json'` because your value will request with HTTP `accept: */*` but if you use `'json'` it will be `accept: application/json`.

#### Option 1

Use content type `application/json`.

The `contentType:` should be `'application/json'` or `'application/json;charset=utf-8'`.

By this content type you will be now able to receive POST data in JSON but you cannot access them with `$_POST` because the data is not valid `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Full code for client side:

```js
var import_data = {
     action: 'start_import',
     sliced_batch: {
        rows_to_add: [],
        rows_to_delete: [],
        rows_to_update: [1,2,3,4,5]
     }
};

function ajax_call(import_data) {
    // ... processes

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'test.php', // url from php file
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", // sending string with cyrillic (ukrainian lng)
        dataType: 'json', // want  to recieve json
        data: JSON.stringify(import_data), 
        success: function(response) { 
           // ... processes import_data ...
           
        },
        error: function(e) {
          // here is where I end up
        }

    });
}
```

Code for PHP:

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
// use $data['sliced_batch'] to access `rows_to_add`, `rows_to_delete` etc.
```

#### Option 2

Use content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

With this content type, you will be able to access `$_POST` properly.

However, to use this request content type in header, the jQuery itself will be modify the value if it is empty jQuery will be just delete it!! So, you need to JSON string only `sliced_batch` property.

Here is the JS code:

```js
var import_data = {
     action: 'start_import',
     sliced_batch: {
        rows_to_add: [],
        rows_to_delete: [],
        rows_to_update: [1,2,3,4,5]
     }
};

function ajax_call(import_data) {
    // ... processes

    // modify `sliced_batch` property to be JSON string to prevent jQuery remove empty properties.
    import_data.sliced_batch = JSON.stringify(import_data.sliced_batch);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'test.php', // url from php file
        type: 'POST',
        // just remove contentType option. It is no need.
        //contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", // sending string with cyrillic (ukrainian lng)
        dataType: 'json', // want  to recieve json
        data: import_data, 
        success: function(response) { 
           // ... processes import_data ...
           
        },
        error: function(e) {
          // here is where I end up
        }

    });
}
```

PHP:

```php
$sliced_batch = ($_POST['sliced_batch'] ?? '');
$sliced_batch = json_decode($sliced_batch, true);
// you can now access $sliced_batch['rows_to_add'], etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks once again to @vee for his explanation, but here's one more thing I'd like to share as it was crucial to get everything to work.

**First**, for json_decode method the JS object keys [should](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) be **double**-quoted, i.e. NOT

```
$bad_json = '{ bar: "baz" }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null
```

or

```
$bad_json = '{ 'bar': "baz" }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null
```

BUT

```
$bad_json = '{ "bar": "baz" }';
json_decode($bad_json); // array("bar" => "baz")
```

**Second and most important!**
When dealing with WordPress it sets its own rules and shows focuses!
Depending on what answer you'd like to get, you may want to use function `wp_unslash()`. Looking at the stringified data in console I saw somth like this:

```
"\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0432\u0435\u0440: \u0424\u0430\u0439\u043b\u0456\u0432 av_imp_p_WEB.csv \u0456 av_imp_p_WEB_previous.csv \u043d\u0435 \u0431\u0443\u043b\u043e \u0432\u0438\u044f\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e. \u041f\u043e\u0447\u0438\u043d\u0430\u044e \u0456\u043c\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442 \u0432\u0441\u044c\u043e\u0433\u043e 
// it is more common for contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

It is the dirty work of WooCommerce (as I read from another's people opinion) and it hinders parsing it the right way, so my full code is:
JS

```
 var import_data = {
          "action": "start_import",
           "sliced_batch": {
           "rows_to_add": my_data1,
           "rows_to_delete": my_data2,
           "rows_to_update": my_data3
            }
};

function ajax_call(import_data) {
 // ... processes
jQuery.ajax({ // ajax to php to save the file to uploads and move it to the plugin's folder
            url: start_import_ajax.url, // url from php file
            type: 'POST',
            //contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", //  what you send
            dataType: 'JSON', // what you would like as a response
            data: {
                "action": import_data.action,
                "sliced_batch": JSON.stringify(import_data.sliced_batch)
            },
                success: function(response) {
                    //response = JSON.parse(response); // if you'd like to console.log  what you've sent
                     console.log(response);
                 }
....
```

PHP

```
 $sliced_batch = wp_unslash($_POST['sliced_batch']);
    $sliced_batch = json_decode($sliced_batch, true);

    $result = start_import($sliced_batch);

    if($result == 0) {
        echo json_encode(["status" => 0]);
    } else echo json_encode(["status" => 1]);
```